# Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' from assembly Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json.net

I spent a good while on google, so if this is a simple fix forgive me but I cannot find anything relating to a fix to this specific issue within C#.

When trying to use the following code it gives me this error:

```cs
string obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(playerObject);
```

```
Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.
```

The only thing I can really find when searching is people running into version mis-match errors, which is not my issue here as far as I can tell.

Full code for reference: ("logHigh" is a logging function I use)

```cs
public void convertToObject(webPlayerObjArray playerObject)
{
   logHigh("Entered function");
   try
   {
      logHigh("Serializing");
      string obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(playerObject);
      logHigh(obj);
      webPlayerObjArray plrobjarr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<webPlayerObjArray>(obj);
      logHigh(plrobjarr.users[0].badgeName);
   }catch (Exception e)
   {
      logHigh(e.Message);
   }
   logHigh("Finished function");
}
```

```cs
webPlayerObjArray playerFile = new webPlayerObjArray();

webObject webObj1 = new webObject();
webObj1.steamID = "test1";
webObj1.badgeName = "test2";
webObj1.weaponSkinName = "test3";
webObj1.sailName = "test4";
webObj1.cannonSkinName = "test5";

webObject webObj2 = new webObject();
webObj2.steamID = "test1";
webObj2.badgeName = "test2";
webObj2.weaponSkinName = "test3";
webObj2.sailName = "test4";
webObj2.cannonSkinName = "test5";

playerFile.users = new webObject[2];
playerFile.users[0] = webObj1;
playerFile.users[1] = webObj2;
logHigh(playerFile.users[0].badgeName);
logHigh(playerFile.users[1].badgeName);
```

Class definitions:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class webObject
{
   public string steamID { get; set; }
   public string badgeName { get; set; }
   public string sailName { get; set; }
   public string weaponSkinName { get; set; }
   public string cannonSkinName { get; set; }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class webPlayerObjArray
{
   public webObject[] users { get; set; }
}
```

Using visual studio 2019
Addition of Newtonsoft done through NuGet package Manager

- Version 12.0.3

Object declarations are temporary. Going to switch to loading json from a webpage later on, but i was just trying to get it to work in the first instance, hence the function name.

There's probably an easy fix, but I have unfortunately been unable to find it thus far.

### Extra information based on comments and testing:

- It's a class library for a game mod, not a web project.
- Adding :

```html
<dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.3" /> //12.0.3.23909 also had no effect
</dependentAssembly>
```

To the `app.config` unfortunately had no effect, whether present or not.

- The Newtonsoft.Json reference within VS 2019 has no warning(s)
- Rebuilding the project has no effect, (had to do this initially as my function refused to run originally as soon as I added any code referencing the DLL, after a successful rebuild I was finally presented with the error above)
- The dll version that is located in `bin\Debug` is the same version as referenced within VS 2019
- Creating a fresh project and copying the code over, did not work
- Changing target framework (either 4.5 or 4.7.2 (and using respective dll version(s)) had no effect
- The following previous versions of Newtonsoft.Json were tried, to no success:

  - 12.0.3
  - 11.0.2
  - 10.0.3
  - 9.0.1
  - 8.0.3

Comment: Make sure the you have `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` file with the correct version being used in the `bin` directory. Check version on properties details tab

Comment: @RuiCaramalho I did, and it is using the same version as mentioned within VS

Comment: Is it Web Project? if yes on `assemblyBinding` in the `<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />` is the next line like this `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.3.0" />`

Comment: @RuiCaramalho No, its a class library for a game mod.

Comment: Another possible solution is delete the `bin` and  `obj` folder and rebuild the project. Make sure you delete correct folders depending if you are on `Debug` or `Release`

Comment: I have tried rebuilding to no effect alas, I had to because originally my function simply did not run when referencing newtonSoft, in doing so is how I finally got the try{}catch(){} to throw the error above. I'll give it another shot, but I doubt it will do much

Comment: In the `Solution Explorer` can you see the Reference to `Newtonsoft.Json` without any Warning?

Comment: Correct, it shows up without any visible warnings.

Comment: The error is complaining of the assembly with version `Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0` but you have mentioned that you are using `12.0.3`. So I guess that's the problem. Check the `app.config` do you have `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.3.0" />` ?

Comment: The app.config has no reference to Newtonsoft.Json, but the packages.config contains `<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.3" targetFramework="net472" />` . The `Bin \ Debug` config also contains no reference to it.

Comment: With reference I should also add that the `NuGet Package Manager` says `v12.0.3` within VS, the DLL itself states `File Version: 12.0.3.23909` in the `\Debug` folder

Comment: the `Alternion.csproj` Does contain a link `<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>`

Comment: try on the `app.config` to add `<runtime><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.3" />
      </dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding></runtime>`

Comment: It's like saying the project that references to 12.0.0.0 should accept the 12.0.3 version

Comment: No change, i also tried using `12.0.3.23909`, but that didn't work either unfortunately

Comment: Sorry I'm out off ideas... when you find the solution, and I think you will ;), please write it here. Good luck

Comment: Will do, i'll update my main post to reflect the attempts here as well. Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it seams it works only with newversion="12.0.0.0" even if you use Version 12.0.3.23909 of Newtonsoft.Json.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" /> 
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

This what I need to do...

I added `Newtonsoft.json` to the project and then those directives below the TargetFramework

In dotnet core the `<dependentAssembly>` it seems is ignored and the those below are the ones that would make it work....

Hope it works for you

The link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection about `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects`

And the `GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType` https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/dd5e8bc3f86ac98bd77d8971b00a6ad14f122f1a/src/XMakeTasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets#L2027

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Flurl.Http" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.json" Version="13.0.1" />

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```